# Target the second and penultimate elements having a specific class with CSS

Tags: html, css, pagination

I have the following code that display a posts pagination structure. I'm wondering if it's possible to target via CSS the **second** and **penultimate** elements having the `.page-numbers` class. If so, how? I have no control over the markup so I cannot add additional classes to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<nav class="pagination">
    <div class="nav-links">
        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/1/">Previous</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/1/">1</a>
        <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/3/">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/4/">4</a>
        <span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/10/">10</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/3/">Next</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: :nth-child(2) and :nth-last-child(2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.page-numbers:nth-last-child(2),.page-numbers:nth-child(2)
    {
    background-color:yellow;
    }

</style>

<nav class="pagination">
    <div class="nav-links">
        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/1/">Previous</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/1/">1</a>
        <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/3/">3</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/4/">4</a>
        <span class="page-numbers dots">&hellip;</span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/10/">10</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://page.com/page/3/">Next</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```